# Oracle recommendations for stablecoin project

Tags: oracles, stablecoins

Looking for an oracle to add to my stablecoin project. Want the essentials (decentralized, censorship-resistant, secure mechanics, no multi-sig to control everything).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Chainlink as a decentralized oracle network for your stablecoin project. Chainlink is a really popular and trusted platform that provides reliable and accurate data feeds to smart contracts. It accomplishes this by utilizing a network of nodes for decentralized data aggregation, and by ensuring data accuracy through a system of reputation and staking.

One of the advantages of Chainlink is its clear and easy-to-follow documentation, which can be found on their website: [Chainlink website](https://chain.link/)

Comment: Appreciate the rec, but they don't really fit the criteria I'm looking for (i.e. not censorship-resistant, multi-sig controls everything)